# How to set inner borders ifor table in iText7

Tags: itext, border, itext7

I have a table created this way.

```
                Table table = new Table(columnNames.Length);
                table.SetWidth(new UnitValue(UnitValue.PERCENT, 100));
                table.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
```

The problem is that SetBorder call only sets external borders of table, not inner borders.

I cannot set border to cells, since cells have margins, so borders appear inside each table cell, so I think there is other way to set that border. It is solid black by default. I need to  change it to solid light gray.

EDIT:

This is what I actually get when setting border for the table and for the cells together. I need the solid black borders to be light gray. Cell border is not the solution since cells have margins, as you see.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify your question by referring to the tutorial using one of the screen shots to demonstrate which type of borders are missing? This is the tutorial page: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have edited the question. It seems that tutorial page does not have the situation I am facing here.The fact is that the cell has margin, so it is not possible to set borders for cell, but by setting border for table, only external border is set, not internal border.

Comment: You can always create a custom cell renderer to achieve what you want. There are several cell renderer examples that you can use for inspiration.